# Proof that $\int_1^e\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(\ln nx)}{n^2+x}dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_1^e\frac{\sin(\ln nx)}{n^2+x}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

In a recent exam I took I was asked to prove that 
$$\int_1^e\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(\ln nx)}{n^2+x}dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_1^e\frac{\sin(\ln nx)}{n^2+x}dx$$
In my answer, I showed that for all $x\in[1,e]$:
$$\left|\frac{\sin(\ln nx)}{n^2+x}\right|\le\frac{1}{n^2+x}\lt\frac{1}{n^2}$$
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, therefore  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(\ln nx)}{n^2+x}$ converges uniformly in $[1,e]$ and by integrating term by term we can conclude that:
$$\int_1^e\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(\ln nx)}{n^2+x}dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_1^e\frac{\sin(\ln nx)}{n^2+x}dx$$
Now this proof seems too simple to me, could someone check if this is correct?

Comment: Looks good. Maybe you want to say that the series converges absolutely uniformly since this is what you get by the Weierstrass $M$-test. This is stronger than uniform convergence so in particular you get what you want.